# AngularJS 2 and Cordova: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: android, cordova, angular, phonegap-build

I am trying to get an Angular2 app running natively on Android using Cordova.
Unfortunately, the app only shows the loading screen of the Angular app but is not able to load the app.

I am getting the following error message:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND     file:///app/styles.css 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND     file:///app/libs-bundle.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND     file:///app/main.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

It seems like all the local resources included in the app cannot be loaded.

Comment: Aside on that, do you have solution to set up project based on AngularJs2 + Cordova?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found the problem:

For the routing inside the Angular2 app I defined the `<base href="/">` tag in the index.html. This works fine when running the app from a web-server. Though, for Cordova/Phonegap it has to be changed to `<base href="file:///android_asset/www/" />`.

Comment: Where can I find that <base href="/">?

Comment: @VinceBanzon In the index file.

Comment: got this to work to my current project. But I can't find your answer here. I might have fixed it someway else. Thanks anyways.

Comment: this will result into continues blinking of app. Do you have any other solution for this.

Answer (score 7):

`<base href="./" />` or `<base href="." />` also works, the same approach. Thanks for your commit, it helped me.

Comment: This also worked for me, but do you guys know why this works?

Comment: @BohaoLI Most of the time, index.html sits in the location of `/` so `.` point to `/`. But here, within Cordova, index.html sits in `file:///android_asset/www/`, so `.` point to `file:///android_asset/www/` and `/` point to `http://`